# How to setup lerna with git-only

Tags: git, lerna

I have a React app using submodules to share code and I want to swap it with lerna. But instead of publishing to NPM, I just want to use *git-only* where the code will be published back to git using commitish. Basically the folder is structured something like this

```
app/
  src/
    components/
    shared/
      ui/
      utilities/
    index.js
  .gitmodules
  package.json
```

All submodules go to under shared. My question is how can I setup lerna so that "app" will have dependency on "ui" and "utilities" using *git-only*?

Is the structure will be like this

```
lerna-app/
  packages/
    app/
    ui/
    utilities/
```

or like this?

```
app/
  packages/
    ui/
    utilities
```